# Can't access external load balancer using AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am not sure why external access is not working, it seems like I followed all tutorials I could find to a T.

In my final docker image i do the following:

```
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

This is my deployment script which deploys my app and a load balancer service. Everything seems to boot up ok. I can tell my .NET Core application is running on port 80 b/c I can get live logs using the azure portal. The load balancer finds the pods from the deployment and shows the appropriate mappings but i still am unable to access them externally. Cannot access in browser, ping nor telnet.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: 2d69-deployment
  labels:
    app: 2d69-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: 2d69
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: 2d69
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: 2d69
        image: 2d69containerregistry.azurecr.io/2d69:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - name: keyvault-cert
            mountPath: /etc/keyvault
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: keyvault-cert
          secret:
            secretName: keyvault-cert
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: 2d69
  labels:
    app: 2d69
spec:
  selector:
    app: 2d69
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

deployment description:
kubectl -n 2d69 describe deployment 2d69

```
Name:                   2d69
Namespace:              2d69
CreationTimestamp:      Fri, 11 Dec 2020 13:23:24 -0500
Labels:                 app=2d69
                        deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 9
Selector:               app=okrx2d69
Replicas:               2 desired | 2 updated | 2 total | 2 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=okrx2d69
  Containers:
   2d69:
    Image:        2d69containerregistry.azurecr.io/2d69:5520
    Port:         80/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/keyvault from keyvault-cert (ro)
  Volumes:
   keyvault-cert:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  keyvault-cert
    Optional:    false
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   2d69-5dbcff8b94 (2/2 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

service description:
kubectl -n 2d69 describe service 2d69

```
Name:                     2d69
Namespace:                2d69
Labels:                   app=2d69
Selector:                 app=2d69
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       ***.***.14.208
LoadBalancer Ingress:     ***.***.***.***
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  32112/TCP
Endpoints:                ***.***.9.103:443,***.***.9.47:443
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31408/TCP
Endpoints:                ***.***.9.103:80,***.***.9.47:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: `kubectl get svc -n 2d69`...that should give you the external IP of your Load Balancer...can you post the output of that command 

Comment: Do you check if you can access the pod via port-forward?

Comment: Lol @Hackerman I omitted public ip for a reason.

Comment: @CharlesXu I could access the pod with kubectl proxy but not publicly. I was using Azure Kubernetes Service as my kube host, I ended up remaking the cluster using azure CNI instead of kubenet which allowed me to add vnet peering to the cluster and deployed with same config as OP.